# Are there any tools or practices for tracking developer IDE&Tool versions?

Tags: ide, version, developer-tools

I am developing on multiple machines and have the repository and/or project-folder on a private cloud.
I would like to have a file or something, that includes every used tool (NP++ v1.x.x, VS2019 v4.x.x, yEd v2 etc.).

I find the idea of the "package.json" for NPM extremly useful. Maybe their is something similar for OS-Level. (Win10 by the way)

Possible solutions I thinked of:

- of course just track it manually
- Virtual Machine (which I don't want to use and cannot host anyway)

The tool/practice/extension/whatever should only track some given IDEs/tools. Not setup a OS from zero.